# I didn't come here for an argument

Tags: meaning, etymology, computing

Is there any consensus on how the word for a heated discussion (which apparently comes from the same root as Silver/Argent) also came to mean a parameter passed to a function?

Edit: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186293/why-are-actual-parameters-called-arguments  Thanks to Mitch. I will leave the question open as I think it's useful.

Comment: Unless you're doing something clever that went over my head, it's actually spelled "argument".

Comment: @DougWarren - sorry typo. I'm a BE native living in AE land so I spend half my time removing unnecessary "u"s from words and the other half accidentally adding them !

Comment: Sorry, this is abuse.

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/186293/why-are-actual-parameters-called-arguments

Comment: @Robusto - it's still an argument....

Comment: @Mitch - thank you, I don't know if I can close a question as a dupe on another site.

Comment: Then it should be migrated or you should cut and paste relative parts of the answers from there, to here. Side note: (my #1 SE pet peeve) I don't come here for titles that mean absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter part of the word comes from "Mathematics and Logic" where it serves as an agent to satisfy the requirements of a given formula or reason.

Since in a heated debate you have to satisfy/justify a reason with an argument, it makes sense for the word to refer to the same root.

Comment: I believe this particular meaning of *argument* in computing and mathematics comes from linguistics:

argument = any of the noun phrases in a clause that are related directly to the verb, typically the subject, direct object, and indirect object.

Comment: @mikeagg - I have the same feeling about a [linguistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_%28linguistics%29) origin. In linguistics, "argument" refers to any expression or syntactic element in a sentence that serves to complete the meaning of the verb.

In English, a verb typically requires from one to three arguments. The number of arguments required by a verb is the valency of that verb. In addition to the predicate and its arguments, a sentence may contain optional elements called adjuncts.